# Can't use API with username and password in Scrapy

Tags: python, curl, scrapy, xe-api

This Curl works.

```
https://<user>:<pass>@xecdapi.xe.com/v1/convert_from.json/?from=1000000&to=SGD&amount=AED,AUD,BDT&inverse=True
```

But this Scrapy request doesn't work.

```
    yield scrapy.Request("https://<user>:<pass>@xecdapi.xe.com/v1/convert_from.json/?from=1000000&to=SGD&amount=AED,AUD,BDT&inverse=True")

It returns this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
    return handler.download_request(request, spider)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 61, in download_request
    return agent.download_request(request)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 286, in download_request
    method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1596, in request
    endpoint = self._getEndpoint(parsedURI)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1580, in _getEndpoint
    return self._endpointFactory.endpointForURI(uri)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1456, in endpointForURI
    uri.port)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\contextfactory.py", line 59, in creatorForNetloc
    return ScrapyClientTLSOptions(hostname.decode("ascii"), self.getContext())
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_sslverify.py", line 1201, in __init__
    self._hostnameBytes = _idnaBytes(hostname)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_sslverify.py", line 87, in _idnaBytes
    return idna.encode(text)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\idna\core.py", line 355, in encode
    result.append(alabel(label))
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\idna\core.py", line 276, in alabel
    check_label(label)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\idna\core.py", line 253, in check_label
    raise InvalidCodepoint('Codepoint {0} at position {1} of {2} not allowed'.format(_unot(cp_value), pos+1, repr(label)))
InvalidCodepoint: Codepoint U+003A at position 28 of u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xecdapi' not allowed
```

Comment: You left your credentials in the second url. And code 500 means that server encountered error while processing your request, so something is wrong with it.

Comment: I update my question. Previously, I didn't turn off Crawlera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrapy does not support HTTP Authentication via URL. We have to use HTTPAuthMiddleware instead.

in `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware': 811,
}
```

in the spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class SomeIntranetSiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

    http_user = 'someuser'
    http_pass = 'somepass'
    name = 'intranet.example.com'

    # .. rest of the spider code omitted ...
```

Comment: Note that there's an open Pull Request with an implementation of reading credentials from URLs: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1466